# Can a main class in java be extended and file name is saved by the sub class?

Tags: java

I was wondering if it is possible to extend a main class in java and file name is saved by the sub class. If yes please show me a working example. If not tell me why.

Comment: Can you show us some code what you mean? A class can be extended in Java and the classname and the filename need to be the same

Comment: Whats a main class? Do you mean the main method? That is static and therefor cannot be extended/overridden in other classes.

Comment: It looks like a homework question... just google it

Comment: yea i mean class which include main method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There no special inheritance restriction in java.

You can have a file called `Base.java` containing the following class with the `main` method.

```
public class Base {
  public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println("Hello World");
  }
}
```

And another file with the name `Factorial.java` containing the following class that inherits the `Base` class.

```
public class Factorial extends Base{


}
```

This is plain inheritance.

Comment: is the vice versa also true. how about if i extends base to factorial in your eg, is that case true as well ?

Comment: Absolutely. it is plain inheritance.